# Can I upgrade Mailman to the latest release via apt-get?

Tags: apt, mailman

I'm running Mailman 2.1.16rc2 on Ubuntu 12.04. That's the most recent version available via apt-get install. Mailman recently released version 2.1.18 with some new features to deal with fallout from [Yahoo's new DMARC policy](http://www.zdnet.com/aol-yahoo-email-problems-show-limits-of-email-security-7000028783/) for email.

Is there any way to install this latest version via apt-get? I'd like to continue using apt-get updates to find new versions of Mailman in the future, but the version I want is not currently available in the standard repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You can use utopic's Mailman 2.1.18 package on trusty. (Source: I am using it, for precisely this reason, see Background below.)

To install it via apt-get, do the following:

1. First, configure the utopic repository by creating a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/utopic.list with these contents:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
2. Next, configure the system so that it does **not** automatically install packages from utopic (since otherwise you will upgrade to utopic the next time you run dist-upgrade). Create a file /etc/apt/preferences.d/utopic with these contents:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=utopic
   Pin-Priority: 100
   ```
3. Finally, install the mailman package, explicitly instructing apt-get to use the utopic version:

   ```
   apt-get update && apt-get install mailman/utopic
   ```

**Caution**

Using packages from a newer release on an older release is not supported. If something goes wrong with this process you will likely be on your own bug-wise. However, I can confirm that my Mailman lists work after doing this.

**Upgrading**

You should remove the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/utopic.list and /etc/apt/preferences.d/utopic files before attempting any upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu from trusty.

**Sources**

These are based on [the Ubuntu Backport instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), substituting "utopic" for "trusty-backports"

**Background**

I also wanted 2.1.18, because the "ALLOW_FROM_IS_LIST = Yes" feature in 2.1.16 is *list-wide*. I don't want to re-write everyone as "from is list", just Yahoo users and others with a DMARC p=reject policy. 2.1.18 has a per-sender feature accessible from Privacy options → Sender filters in an individual list's admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to install the latest version of mailman(2.1.18) via apt-get until the repositories are updated.

The current  version of mailman package avilable in the main repository is 2.1.16-2.

```
$ apt-cache policy mailman
mailman:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.1.16-2
  Version table:
     1:2.1.16-2 0
        500 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to /usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/mm_cfg.py

```
ALLOW_FROM_IS_LIST = Yes
```

Then a new option **from_is_list** will appear on each list's "General Options" page.

Comment: Can you post a link to some reference? An uptodate manpage or release notes or some official tutorial/guide?

Comment: @muru: Look here → https://wiki.list.org/DOC/What%20can%20I%20do%20about%20members%20being%20unsubscribed%20by%20bounces%20of%20Yahoo%20user's%20posts%20for%20DMARC%20policy%20reasons%3F